Replace an embedded unix-style LF
I have a text file with a line feed in the middle of one of the values. In Notepad++, when showing all characters, this is what the file looks like.
text file with line feeds shown
Row1-Col1,Row1-Col2,Row1-Col3,Row1-Col4,Row1-Col5
Row2-Col1,Row2-Col2,Row2-Col3,Row2-Col4,Row2-Col5
Row3-Col1,Row3-Col2,Row3-Col3,Row3-
Col4,Row3-Col5
Row4-Col1,Row4-Col2,Row4-Col3,Row4-Col4,Row4-Col5
Row5-Col1,Row5-Col2,Row5-Col3,Row5-Col4,Row5-Col5

Using Powershell, I need to eliminate the line feed after "Row3-" to have the data look like this:
Row1-Col1,Row1-Col2,Row1-Col3,Row1-Col4,Row1-Col5
Row2-Col1,Row2-Col2,Row2-Col3,Row2-Col4,Row2-Col5
Row3-Col1,Row3-Col2,Row3-Col3,Row3-Col4,Row3-Col5
Row4-Col1,Row4-Col2,Row4-Col3,Row4-Col4,Row4-Col5
Row5-Col1,Row5-Col2,Row5-Col3,Row5-Col4,Row5-Col5

I have tried the following, but the generated file is identical to the source file.
(Get-Content -Raw $SourceFile).Replace('`nC','C') | Out-File ".\\fixLF.txt" -NoNewline\

Note that the actual data in the file is more complex than this. However, the line that I need to eliminate will always have the same character after it.

Note that out-file defaults to utf16 encoding in powershell 5.1.


.Replace is an instance method of the String class, it knows nothing about regex. The replacement regex operator in PowerShell is -replace.
The patterns you could use to fix your file could be (?m)\r?\n^(?=C):
(Get-Content -Raw $SourceFile) -replace '(?m)\r?\n^(?=C)' | Out-File ".\\fixLF.txt" -NoNewline\

Or (?<=-)\r?\n:
(Get-Content -Raw $SourceFile) -replace '(?<=-)\r?\n' | Out-File ".\\fixLF.txt" -NoNewline\

Using .Replace might also work, however you must use double-quotes "..." instead so that `n can expand as a new-line character:
(Get-Content -Raw $SourceFile).Replace("`nC", 'C') | Out-File ".\\fixLF.txt" -NoNewline\


I believe there is no really a way to do it easily with a regex, because the EndOfLine is the same no matter how long is the line.
Which means you need to find what lines are abnormally short, merge them together in a new string, remove the original lines and insert the new string in their place.
So something like this:
$FileContent = Get-Content -Path $FilePath

$CommaCount = ($FileContent[0] -split ',').Count

$NewFile = for ($Line = 0; $Line -lt $FileContent.Count; $Line++) {
    if (($FileContent[$Line] -split ',').Count -lt $CommaCount) {
        '{0}{1}' -f $FileContent[$Line], $FileContent[$Line + 1]
        $Line++    
    }
    else {
        $FileContent[$Line]
    }
        
}

$NewFile | Set-Content -Path $FilePath

I'm going to guess there are more efficient ways to do this, but I do not know them

Or with regex (in the console there's no \r, but in a script there is):
'Row1-Col1,Row1-Col2,Row1-Col3,Row1-Col4,Row1-Col5
Row2-Col1,Row2-Col2,Row2-Col3,Row2-Col4,Row2-Col5
Row3-Col1,Row3-Col2,Row3-Col3,Row3-
Col4,Row3-Col5
Row4-Col1,Row4-Col2,Row4-Col3,Row4-Col4,Row4-Col5
Row5-Col1,Row5-Col2,Row5-Col3,Row5-Col4,Row5-Col5' -replace '\nc','c'

Row1-Col1,Row1-Col2,Row1-Col3,Row1-Col4,Row1-Col5
Row2-Col1,Row2-Col2,Row2-Col3,Row2-Col4,Row2-Col5
Row3-Col1,Row3-Col2,Row3-Col3,Row3-col4,Row3-Col5
Row4-Col1,Row4-Col2,Row4-Col3,Row4-Col4,Row4-Col5
Row5-Col1,Row5-Col2,Row5-Col3,Row5-Col4,Row5-Col5

